# Не могу подключить std::string_view

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Подключаю заголовочный файл string_view, но компилятор упорно пишет что string_view не является членом std, если я пытаюсь его использовать. В чем может быть проблема ? VS 19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По умолчанию, 2019 студия не использует с++17. Его нужно "включить ручками" - добавить опцию компилятору `/std:c++17` - https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=vs-2019